# Wordpress per-category feeds have generic titles

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm actually not sure if this is a configuration issue (with the theme) or a PHP issue (in which the relevant template simply is buggy)... I have a Wordpress-powered blog in which I make extensive use of categories to group posts. However, the per-category syndication feeds produce items whose titles are just the name of the blog and the category name itself. Unfortunately, my grasp of PHP in general, and Wordpress-theme-specific PHP in particular is fairly weak at this point. Without going into the details of the theme itself, can someone point me to some general areas I can look at first, before I *do* break out the minute detail?

Comment: can you give us a link to look at?

Comment: Go to http://www.dereferenced.com -- look at the feed (from the location-bar icon). Then click on any of the categories for the first post... when on the category page look at the feed again and you'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

One of the feed URLs in the header does show the category with /feed/ at the end of the URL, but the feed link that appears next to the comments link and post date is not a complete fed URL, i.e., not ending in /feed/ . So I think there's confusion on the themes' part as to the link being a feed - because it's right next to the feed icon - or just a link to that category of posts, like many WP themes have.

You could modify the theme to have an RSS link there instead of the category. This will display a feed lnk for whatever category page isbeing displayed:

```
<?php
$this_category = get_category($cat);// This line just gets the active category information
print '<a href="'.get_category_feed_link($this_category->cat_ID, '').'">Subscribe</a>';
?>
```